# Symfony2 disable form label html escape

Tags: forms, symfony, escaping, label

I have a form label printed like this:

```
{% set txt = 'Im OK with the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>' %}
{{ form_label(form.terms, txt) }}
```

But obviously this will escape the html tag and will print something like this:

```
<label>Im OK with the &lt;a href="#"&gt;terms and conditions&lt;/a&gt;</label>
```

Is there a way to disable the html escaping for this label only?
I've already tried:

```
{{ form_label(form.terms, txt|raw) }}
...
{{ form_label(form.terms, txt)|raw }}
...
{% autoescape false %}
{{ form_label(form.terms, txt) }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that works, but I'm not sure is the best one, is to set the label tag manually:

```
<label for="{{ form.terms.vars.id }}">{{ txt|raw }}</label>
```

Comment: Definitely not the best one possible, but apparently the best one available. :(